# How to achieve multiline on each list item depends on the number of contents which flexible length in ListView

Tags: flutter, listview, gridview

I'm trying to develop a UI like below with ListView in flutter.

I have looked at Gridview, TableView, etc. and cannot figure out how to achieve the following layout.
In Swift, a similar layout was realized by placing a UICollectionView inside a UITableView's UITableViewCell.
It seems that GridView does not automatically wrap by the number of cells (Container), and it would be helpful if you could give me an approach or sample code for achieving such a layout.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved this question by myself using Wrap widget in List Item simply.